# Multivariate Linear Regression in Python - analog of mvregress in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I want to use the same function or method in Python as [mvregress](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvregress.html) in MATLAB.
As an example, we have `x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6` inputs and `y1, y2, y3` outputs. After using this function we should get some estimate regression coefficients. 
Does Python have this ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` works fine for **multivariate** linear regression (where the output is a **vector**, not a scalar)

```
>>> from sklearn import linear_model
>>> X = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
>>> Y = [[1, 2, 3]]
>>> lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
>>> model = lr.fit(X, Y)
>>> model.predict([[1,2,3,4,5,6]])
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
```